# Software for drawing circuit schematics and SPICE simulations on Mac?

Tags: schematics, simulation, spice, software

**Problem**:

I'm trying to find a robust, user friendly, schematic design and SPICE simulation software that will run on a Mac.  I have used Multisim for design and simulation in the past.

I'm wondering if there are any equivalent programs out there that I'm not aware of.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) available if you want to avoid asking [off-topic](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) recommendations here.

Comment: I figured since this is for electrical engineering and my question refers to circuit simulation and schematics, this would be the better place to ask since software recommendations covers a wide range of software not pertaining to EE, where as here I am more likely to get recommendations from electrical engineers.

Comment: That still doesn't make it on-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LTSpice is now available as a native Mac application.

The schematic are not as pretty as other applications but the simulation works well.

Comment: There's always LTspiceIV, as an alternative.